# Delegate defined in class B does not get called when used in class A

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I currentl have a class B which inhertis from the AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate protocol, which is set on B's initiazation, however, when i try to use this delegate inside class A, the protocol methods ends up not being called. E.g it looks something like this:

```
class A {
    private var photoOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
    
    @objc func captureFrame() {
        ...
        let b = B(a: self)
        photoOutput.capturePhoto(with: photoSettings, delegate: b)
    }

    func somemethod() {
        ...
    }

}

class B: AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {
    weak var a: A?
    weak var delegate: AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate?

    init(a: A) {
        self.a = a
        super.init()
        self.delegate = self
    }
    
    // photoOutput does not end up getting called...
    func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
        print("Delegate method called")
        a.somemethod()
    }
}
```

The reason that i want to do it like this is that the captureFrame method might end up being called in an iteration and we want to persist some data passed in as agurments to avoid race conditions.

It's quite possible that i've misunderstood how this should work.

I have also tried calling the delegate variable direcrly, e.g:

```
photoOutput.capturePhoto(with: photoSettings, delegate: b.delegate)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to consider how you want to manage the lifetime of `B` here. At the end of `captureFrame`, there's no reference to `b` anymore, so it is released. You likely want to manage it as a property of `A`, maybe along these lines:

```
class A {
    lazy var b: B = B(a: self)

    @objc func captureFrame() { ... }
}
```

This would allow all calls to `captureFrame` to share a single B (which could be correct). Alternately, you could hold them in a Dictionary or Array if you need to manage separate instances of B for each call.

If you want calls to `captureFrame` to cancel previous in-progress calls, then @Shehata's approach is a way to do that (though I would use a regular Optional there rather than `!`). Every time `b` is set, it releases the previous object.

---

Based on your comments below about managing multiple calls, and dealing with a payload, I believe this is the approach you're looking for:

```
class A {
    private var photoOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()

    // I don't know what your "payload" is, but it doesn't matter
    typealias Payload = String

    // A dictionary of all "in-flight" captures based on their uniqueID
    var captures: [Int64: Payload] = [:]

    // All captures share the same delegate
    lazy var b = B(a: self)

    @objc func captureFrame(attach payload: Payload) {

        // Every capture requires its own settings
        let photoSettings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()

        // Request the capture
        photoOutput.capturePhoto(with: photoSettings, delegate: b)

        // Store the ID of the capture in the "in-flight" dictionary
        captures[photoSettings.uniqueID] = payload
    }

    func somemethod(output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
        let id = photo.resolvedSettings.uniqueID

        // Look up the payload in the "in-flight" dictionary (and remove it)
        if let payload = captures.removeValue(forKey: id) {
            // process output, photo, and payload, considering possible errors
        }
    }
}

class B: NSObject, AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {
    weak var a: A?

    // I removed `delegate` here. I'm not sure what it was for.

    init(a: A) {
        self.a = a
        super.init()
    }

    func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
        print("Delegate method called")

        // Just pass all the data back to `A`. 
        // Or you could some processing here, and pass it back to A.
        // Just make sure to pass the uniqueID in some way.
        a?.somemethod(output: output, photo: photo, error: error)
    }
}
```

Comment: I only want to preserve data for the current capture. I can't share the full code, but in captureFrame we basically revice a payload as an argument which we later want to attach to the correct image, if that makes sense. However, if a capture is processing, i don't want to cancel that, then i want it to finish processing while the next one waits in queue

Comment: Do you mean you want to wait for `didFinishProcessingPhoto` to complete before calling `capturePhoto` again? Or do you want to go ahead and call `capturePhoto` immediately, and just combine it with the correct data in the end? (My assumption would be the latter.) Do you understand how to do that with a Dictionary, or are you looking for help with that?

Comment: Yes, your assumption is correct. Your solution is a bit more elegant than what i was initially trying, so thank you! :)